# React/Redux: Why are my my properties in this.props undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to set up Redux in React for the first time and I can't seem to pass my initial state from the store to the component. My store file is setting state to the return value of the reducer. [Here is what happens when I log this.props to the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7P0g.png)

**Component**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { exampleAction } from '../../actions';

class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }

    render() {
      console.log(this.props)
      return (
        <div>
          <p>this is {this.props.examplePropOne}</p>
        </div>
      );
    } 
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    examplePropOne: state.examplePropOne,
    examplePropTwo: state.examplePropTwo
  });

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators({ exampleAction }, dispatch)
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

**Reducer**

```js
import { EXAMPLE_ACTION } from './../actions/types'

const initialState = {
  examplePropOne : 'Example Property One',
  examplePropTwo : 'Example Property Two'
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case EXAMPLE_ACTION: 
      return {
        ...state,
        examplePropOne: action.payload
      }
    default: 
      return state
  }
}
```

**Action**

```js
import { EXAMPLE_ACTION } from './types'


export const exampleAction = text =>  ({
  type: EXAMPLE_ACTION,
  payload: text,
})
```

**[Edit]**

[Here is what happens when I log the state within mapStateToProps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6C4H.png)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import reducers from '../reducers';


export const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    state: reducers
  }),
);
```

Comment: Can you describe what is logged if you put `console.log(state);` inside `mapStateToProps()`? You'll have to restructure the function temporarily a bit. Also can you please share how you are registering the reducer with your store (`createStore()`)?

Comment: I have added that into the question does that help? In my question I changed the initial state from 'I am property one' to 'Example Property One' so that is why it's logging differently from the initial state in my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With how `combineReducers()` was used with `state` passed in as a key, your `mapStateToProps()` would need to look like this instead to access `examplePropOne` and `examplePropTwo`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  examplePropOne: state.state.examplePropOne,
  examplePropTwo: state.state.examplePropTwo
});
```

Given  that [combineReducers()](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers):

> The state produced by combineReducers() namespaces the states of each
>   reducer under their keys as passed to combineReducers()

The issue is that:

```
export const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    state: reducers
  }),
);
```

The key `state` passed to `combineReducers()` created a namespace/property of `state`. With the argument named `state` for the `mapStateToProps()`, requires that properties are accessed as `state.state`. This can probably be resolved by instead giving the key passed to `combineReducers()` a more descriptive name representing what is being used to manage in the store. For example, if it's related to authentication, it could be called some like `auth`. It would look like:

```
export const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    auth: reducers
  }),
);

// ...

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  examplePropOne: state.auth.examplePropOne,
  examplePropTwo: state.auth.examplePropTwo
});
```

Hopefully that helps!